# How do I create a new branch from the existing remote branch on GitHub using CLI?

Tags: git, github

I'm a newbie to Git/GitHub.

Actually,I know how to create a new branch from the existing remote branch on GitHub by GitHub GUI Interface like below.

[Creating and deleting branches within your repository](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository/)

The CLI(Command Line) for this procedure is correct below?

> git checkout -b **new_branch_name** *origin/existing_branch_name_on_git_hub*

Does anyone tell me a exact way?

Answer (score 9):

It is correct, once you have:

- either cloned the GitHub repo
- or do a git fetch, in order to update the remote branch

Then a `git branch -av` will show you all the branches including `origin/existing_branch`.

And you can create a new branch with

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name origin/existing_branch_name_on_git_hub
```

But on the first push, do:

```
git push -u origin new_branch_name
```

That will add an [upstream (tracking) reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-branchltnamegtmerge).